# Open Call Hierarchy fails to find callers in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a couple of Java projects in Eclipse. I can build the project and also run the application from Eclipse. However, when I right click on a method of a class and select "Open Call Hierarchy", I get the "The resource is not on a build path of a Java project." error message. I have all of the src files in the Source tab of the Java Build Path properties window.

Comment: Sounds like eclipse is confused. Try closing all the projects, restarting eclipse, reopening all the projects and then using Project > clean to force a clean build of your projecs.

Comment: Mostly Eclipse Clean is good for when Eclipse gets a scrambled idea of the state of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

- Calling eclise with eclipse.exe -clean -refresh forces Eclipse to rebuild the index. After that the feature worked again.
- Closing and re-opening the project.

Answer (score 0):

If your eclipse version is 2019-03,then this was a bug(https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545293). Try to upgrade your eclipse or install a newer version. For me installing a newer version(latest version Eclipse 2019-09) solved the problem.